# Delete old backup folders from directory using cron

Tags: command-line, backup, cron

I'm trying to get crontab to automatically remove backup folders in a directory apart from the most recent 6 folders as a backup is created in the directory every day.

All my backup folders are just datestamps e.g: 2017_12_29.

When I run `rm -rf $(ls -1 /BACKUPDIR/ | head -n -6)` from a terminal it deletes all folders except the most recent 6 which is what I expect it to do, but it doesn't seem to do anything when crontab runs it and nothing is deleted from the directory.

I'm not sure where I'm going wrong here.

EDIT:
Currently I'm just using rsync to clone the / directory excluding a few directories.

This is what it looks like in root's crontab:

```
00 22 * * * /usr/bin/rsync -aqvHAXS --exclude /dev/ --exclude /proc/ --exclude /sys/ --exclude /tmp/ --exclude /run/ --exclude /mnt/ --exclude /media/ --exclude /lost+found/ --delete / /BACKUPDIR/$(date +\%Y_\%m_\%d)
```

Comment: It can be a permission problem, does the script under cron run with the appropriate user to be able to delete things in `/BACKUPDIR/` ? As a simple debug, put under cron something like `ls -1 /BACKUPDIR/ | head -n -6 > /tmp/debug 2>&1 ` and see what appears in `/tmp/debug`. Also, if not already, have a look at `rsnapshot` tool it handles all things for you automatically.

Comment: Can you update your question with your script, your crontab setup and permissions for both?

Comment: [Why you shouldn't parse the output of `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)

Comment: I've added the script now as an edit, the scripts are all running from root's crontab.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Parsing `ls` is not a good idea at all](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs), so here's a solution I consider more stable:

```
find /BACKUPDIR/ -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d -print0 | sort -z | head -zn-6 | xargs -0 echo rm -rf
```

This just prints the `rm` command for testing purposes, if it does what you want remove `echo` and simply add it to your crontab, e.g. to run every Sunday at 18:00:

```
00 18 * * 0 find /BACKUPDIR/ -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d -print0 | sort -z | head -zn-6 | xargs -0 rm -rf
```

Comment: Permissions might still be the problem if it is e.g. not the root's crontab but the users'.

Comment: @derHugo OP executes `rm -rf` from a terminal and it works – I take that as a sign permissions are not a problem here.

Comment: I've just added this into root's crontab now and it's worked perfectly, I see where I was going wrong before by parsing `ls`. Marked as correct answer thanks for the help.

Comment: @dessert what's the reason for head -zn-6 ?

Comment: @Seth This spares the six most recent folders as requested in the question.

Comment: @dessert I'm on CentOs 7 and I get this error: head: invalid option -- 'z'

Comment: @Seth Looks like CentOs’s version of `head` doesn’t have this option. For CentOs and other Unices there’s [unix.se].